# Event triggered by scroll is not triggered on refreshing/reloading

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have this jQuery code which slides my image from right to left when I scroll past a certain point, but when I reload the page from a position which triggers the effect, it does not automatically show the effect.

I manually have to scroll up or down to trigger the effect. I want the effect to take place when I reload the page also and not just when I scroll down.

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var wScroll=$(window).scrollTop();
    var featureIphone=$(".feature-iphone-img").offset().top;
    var feature1=$("#feature-1").offset().top;
    console.log(wScroll);
    if(wScroll > featureIphone/1.2){
        $(".feature-iphone-img img").addClass("slide-right");
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```css
.feature-iphone-img img{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:30px;
    transition:all 1s ease;
    transform:translate(-800px);
}
.slide-right{
    transform:translate(-180px) !important; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="feature-iphone-img">
    <img src="img/iphone_password.png" class="img-responsive" alt="iphone"/>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(window).scroll(...).trigger('scroll');`

Comment: Thankyou! this solved